# How to customize the email notifications generated by cruisecontrol.sourceforge

Tags: cruisecontrol

I'm using Redhat server as the build server and JDK 7 for my application. I have CruiseControl installed which builds and sends email notifications. Apart from the testng unit tests I have some other web tests for which the results are built as an html file through the ant script and sent out as a separate email. I need to customize the cruisecontrol email notification such that I integrate this email into the cruisecontrol notification email. Which files of CruiseControl do I modify and where do I need to include this information so that the email notifications contain the data I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the xslfilelist attribute of the htmlemail publisher to
specify only the sections you'd like to email.  Using that, too, you could
provide your own custom xsl and send out almost any html email that you'd
like.